# git ignore certain sub directory / folder and its content

Tags: git, ignore

I have the following directory structure:

```
ls -l experiment/

foo.sh
gen__20190425_144843
gen__20190425_144854
bar.yml
```

in which gen___ are folders.

How do i write the .gitignore file to:

- keep track of foo.sh and bar.yml
- and not keep track of all the gen___ folders

I've tried this but does not work (still tracks the gen folders)

```
./experiment/gen__*/*
!./experiment/foo.sh
!./experiment/bar.yml
```

Comment: Are the gen files already tracked? You'll need to remove them from git. `git rm -r --cached .` Then add everything back `git add .`

Comment: no the gen folders are not tracked @EncryptedWatermelon

Comment: Unless you are blacklisting everything with `*`. All you need is `experimental/gen__*`

Comment: Have you tried /experiment/gen__*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`experiment/gen__*` should be enough as the following example shows:

```sh
~$ mkdir test
~$ cd test
~/test$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/mh/test/.git/
~/test$ touch foo.sh
~/test$ touch bar.yml
~/test$ mkdir gen__20190425_144843
~/test$ touch gen__20190425_144843/1
~/test$ touch gen__20190425_144843/2
~/test$ mkdir gen__20190425_144854
~/test$ touch gen__20190425_144854/3
~/test$ touch gen__20190425_144854/4
~/test$ tree
.
├── bar.yml
├── foo.sh
├── gen__20190425_144843
│   ├── 1
│   └── 2
└── gen__20190425_144854
    ├── 3
    └── 4

2 directories, 6 files
~/test$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    bar.yml
    foo.sh
    gen__20190425_144843/
    gen__20190425_144854/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
~/test$ echo "gen__*" > .gitignore
~/test$ cat .gitignore 
gen__*
~/test$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
    bar.yml
    foo.sh

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggests, i end up using the following:

```
experiment/gen__*/*
!experiment/foo.sh
!experiment/bar.yml
```

The important thing is to **use the naked directory name**:

- correct: `experiment/`
- incorrect: `./experiment/`